# When I Make my (ASMX) web service accept/return JSON instead of XML, is it no longer considered SOAP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, soap, asmx

Just trying to wrap my head around SOAP vs REST.  We currently have some asmx web services, mostly used between our own JavaScript and server code (not a public API).  When I specify my method as a `ScriptService` and specify a `ResponseFormat` of Json, is it still considered just a SOAP service?  It still doesn't feel RESTful to me, but maybe thats because of the way my "resources" are designed (not well/fully represented by rest).

EDIT:  Reading more I might be confusing the *format* (JSON vs XML) with the fact that most descriptions of the SOAP *protocol* tie in XML.  For example, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) states:

> It relies on Extensible Markup
> Language (XML) for its message format

To me logically that says if I'm using JSON I must not be using SOAP.

Comment: The format of the data that is returned is irrelevant to REST. REST is about modeling resources, not what format you represent them in. SOAP was designed before JSON existed and when XML was the bee's knees. So I wouldn't be surprised if SOAP always wants to return XML, although that's just a guess (I haven't used SOAP in almost a decade now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define what kind of requests are made to you web service (asmx). Many protocols are allowed:
HTTP POST,
HTTP GET,
SOAP 1.1,
SOAP 1.2,
etc... OR you can block any of them.

When you call the web service with javascript you can use POST or GET. It doesn't matter. The trick is what type of content you tell the service to return in these calls. You can tell the service to send you JSON or you can tell the service to send you XML.

When you create a service client in Visual Studio to connect to a ASMX service, Visual studio will try to access the WSDL for the service and the client will be in charge of generating the SOAP envelopes to communicate with the service and in this case you will send and receive XML because thats what the client and server have agreed to use to communicate.

Comment: So in javascript if I use XmlHttp and POST with a SoapAction header I'm really using HTTP and not SOAP protocols?

Comment: No, if you use a SoapAction header, and send a SOAP envelope, then you're using SOAP.

Comment: SOAP is more related to the way you assemble your request. The request is still sent through a HTTP call.

Comment: That makes sense, because SOAP is on top of/relies on HTTP.  So I think this answers my question in that when I request JSON I'm just using HTTP Post.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't exactly what you asked, but ASMX services are not RESTful if you're calling them from JavaScript and retrieving JSON.  You must make a POST request to ASMX services to get JSON out of them, even if the request is idempotent and only retrieves data.  In a RESTful API, a GET request would be used in that case, not POST.

That's not to say that the lack of RESTfulness is an actual problem for a private API.  I've found ASMX services as a JSON-based service layer for AJAX callbacks works great in practice.